# Ajax query string not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am unable to retrieve the values from Query String when using AJAX

**My JavaScript**

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var serurl = 'http://mydummyurl.com/?lat='+latitude+'&lon='+longitude;
        $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: serurl
    });
  });
}
getLocation();
```

**And, I am trying to use**

```
echo $_GET['lat']; // This is working fine.
echo $_GET['lon']; // This is **NOT WORKING.**
```

Also, if I tweak the URL like `http://mydummyurl.com/?lon='+longitude+'&lat='+latitude+'`

Then `$_GET['lon']` is working and `$_GET['lat']` is not working.

Comment: Well, it would sure seem that there is a problem with your `longitude` value. Have you checked what value it has before the AJAX request? Have you done a `print_r($_GET)` to double-check what values `$_GET` _does_ have?

Comment: Change type from `type: 'POST'`, to `type: 'GET'`,

Comment: @JLRishe - Nope, not a problem with JLRishe, if you look at my last two lines I tweaked the URL and longitude works fine.

Comment: @Alexander - I tried that before and also now, it didn't help.

Comment: @lock Ok, I misread what you said. Still, can you `console.out(serurl)` and tell us what value the URL actually has?

Comment: What are you mean with "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ajax` method expects the query string to be specified separately from the url, either as an object or string, like

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://mydummyurl.com',
   data: { 'lat': latitude, 'lon':longitude }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://mydummyurl.com',
   data:'lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude
});
```

So if your server needs the values to be in `$_GET`, you will need to use `type: 'GET'`